# Magento saves wrong date when generating or updating products in backend

Tags: date, magento, save, product

i've got the problem that sometimes when i add or update a product with a certain attributeset, the date-value in one of the attributes changes after saving. It seems, that this problem only occurs on our live-system. In another forum i've read something about Magentos way handling the date() function is kinda unusual . I don't know whether there is a connection or not.

I would would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you provide the specifics of the problem you are having? For example, can you clarify if this a user-input field? What are you entering in? What is being saved? What timezone are you in? Your live system?

Answer (score 2):

Please do clarify what sdek asked for, but I'm going to make a gigantic logical leap here and take a guess at your problem.

Magento stores dates in GMT in the database, which will make no sense whatsoever if you are also adding data to the system using things like `strtotime`. Your dates will appear to be off by your GMT offset (mine is -8). How this might happen depends on what you might be doing to add products other than simply adding them within the normal interface.

If that is not at all what you are asking about, feel free to disregard :)

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Part 1: First of all, thanks for the reply. And sorry for the lack of detail. So, here are some more facts. 
My timezone is GMT+1:00. The date attribute (end of sale) is entered by a user into an input-field (type datetime). It is just a ordinary datetime attribute that was added to an already existing attributeset.
The date format is a german or european format of the kind of dd.mm.YY. The date is entered by using the calendar function (which is automatically provided by magento) most of the time elsewise it is entered directly either as dd.mm.YY or dd.mm.YYYY (with 0 e.g. 05.01.11).

Comment: Part 2: For our live system we are using a debian server.
I don't know if there are any known issues like that. Also for some reason in the last days the error didn't occur. Oh, and by the way, yes i'm sure that i inserted the correct date ;). Maybe there was something wrong with the servertime. I'll watch that for a while and hopefully it won't happen again.
In any case thanks for the immediate help. I appreciated that.